# When i debug my UWP App gives error related to Component DLL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have Windows 10 (1803) installed on my PC and Visual Studio 17. I have recently downloaded Windows SDK but there are two versions get downloaded i.e., 10.0.17763.132 and 10.0.17134.12. Now i have created my first sample app and when i  debug it on my Local Machine it gives error as Unable to debug windows store app.....A component dll could not be found. if failure continues,ty disabling any installed add ins or repairing your installation. But i have created app with Target 1803 so why this error get shown?.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask], and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Uninstalled and again Installed complete VS2017 resolved issue.

Comment: yeah sometimes that is the only way left - glad you solved it!

Comment: Well done, May I convert your comments to the answer for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> .A component dll could not be found

For this error, you could try to reinstall UWP sdk, then repaired your visual studio. Certainly, you could also reinstall Visual Studio.